# Azure Data Factory - GUID Look Up

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, azure-data-factory

I am working on a SQL to CRM copy data mapping. I want to either update an account record if it exists or insert a new one.

In CRM the accound_id GUID field is the primary key. I want to be able to look that up in CRM if it exists or generate a new one.

I think I am already generating one correctly:

```
SELECT
CAST(NULL as uniqueidentifier) AS ACCOUNTID,
A.VENDORACCOUNTNUMBER AS ACCOUNTNO,
11 AS ACCOUNTTYPE,
VENDORORGANIZATIONNAME AS LEGALACCOUNTNAME,
VENDORSEARCHNAME AS ACCOUNTNAME,
CURRENCYCODE AS CURRENCY,
DEFAULTDELIVERYTERMSCODE AS DELIVERYTERMS,
DEFAULTDELIVERYMODEID AS MODEOFDELIVERY,
CASHDISCOUNTCODE AS CASHTERMS,
DEFAULTPAYMENTTERMSNAME AS PAYMENTTERMS,
'YES' AS ISPRIMARY,
'BILL TO' AS ADDRESSPURPOSE,
A.ADDRESSDESCRIPTION AS BILLTONAME,
A.ADDRESSCOUNTRYREGIONID AS BILLTOCOUNTRY,
A.ADDRESSCOUNTYID AS BILLTOCOUNTY,
A.ADDRESSCITY AS BILLTOCITY,
A.ADDRESSSTATEID AS BILLTOSTATE,
A.ADDRESSSTREET AS BILLTOST,
A.ADDRESSZIPCODE AS BILLTOZIP,
A.FORMATTEDPRIMARYADDRESS AS BILLTOADDRESS,
PRIMARYPHONENUMBER AS BILLTOPHONE,
PRIMARYPHONENUMBERDESCRIPTION AS BILLTOPHONEDESC,
'199 - CORPORATE' AS DISTRICTNAME,
'f97564c6-93a1-e311-9696-6c3be5a8ce94' AS DISTRICT
FROM [dbo].[VendVendorV2Staging] A
WHERE A.ADDRESSLOCATIONROLES = 'Business';
```

What I don't know is how to look up a GUID if it exits or use a new one.

Comment: As I understand, you want copy the GUID from SQL and insert/update the the GUID in CRM if it exists?

Comment: No. I have a account record. I want to check if it exists, if so update, otherwise insert. In CRM, GUID is a Primary Key. So, I am passing it in as NULL or it throws an error. I need some way for me to get the GUID from CRM if it exists and pass it to the mapping. I am not sure how it works to be honest.

Comment: Did you check my answer?

Comment: @ahsatan other questions, account record also has the column GUID, you want copy the GUID and all the column from SQL to CRM, If the account record GUID is exist in CRM then update it, and if the GUID in SQL is not exist, then insert it, am I right?

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure an alternate key in CRM side for account entity, then you can do upsert (update if exists or else create) based on that key. [Read more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/36657/adf-v2-define-keys-for-upsert-behavior.html)

If you don’t want do that, then you can always query the CRM and check for existence before create a new record based on some unique attribute like name, phone number or email.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Additional column feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-overview#add-additional-columns-during-copy) in ADF copy activity to generate a guild value column as shown below.

[image]

As Dynamics CRM supports Upsert, you can set the `write behavior` of your sink settings as `Upsert` and `Ignore Null values` as `True` as shown below. You can leave the `alternate Key` as empty if primary key is used ([Define alternate keys for an entity](https://learn.microsoft.com/dynamics365/customerengagement/on-premises/developer/define-alternate-keys-entity) -  An alternate key is used to uniquely identify a record in Customer Engagement in place of the primary key).

And then map the `AdditionalGuidColumn` to the destination upsert column i.e., `accound_id` GUID field which is the primary key.

[image]

For additional info about Dynamics sink settings, please refer to this doc: [Dynamics as a sink type](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/data-factory/connector-dynamics-crm-office-365#dynamics-as-a-sink-type)

[image]